# conic section, Circle

Tags: complex-numbers, circles, conic-sections

As far as I know and have read, the following equation has no answer
x^2 + y^2 = -a^2

From the point of view of conic sections, the circle is obtained when the cutting plane is parallel to the plane of the circle producing the cone.

> My question is, how is this cut that has no answer?

Because I think there is answer no matter how it is cut.

is it related to complex numbers?

Comment: Note that squares of real numbers are non-negative.  But what about $a=x=y=0$?

Comment: It does have solutions over $\Bbb C$. In fact, any conic section (i.e. plane quadratic curve) has genus $0$ and is birationally equivalent to $\Bbb P^1$, the projective line. Therefore it must have infinitely many points over any algebraically closed field. When you say "has no answer", you are probably refering to a coefficient field such as $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$. Note also that it has solutions over many finite fields as well.

Answer (score 3):

For conic sections, $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.  For real $x$ and $y$, $x^2 \geq 0$, $y^2 \geq 0$ and
$$  x^2 + y^2 \geq 0  \text{.}  $$

But then $-a^2 \leq 0$.  The only possibility for a solution is obtained when $a = 0$ and the conic section is a point, a circle with radius $0$.